# How to Use JQuery Autocomplete plugin with Page Methods?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a page web method as following:

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static string[] GetStoreIds(string beginWith)
    {
        var dataSource = new[] { "1", "12", "21", "31", "13", "23" };
        return (from storeId in dataSource
                where storeId.Contains(beginWith)
                select storeId).ToList().ToArray();
    }
```

Is it posssible to use JQuery Autocomplete plugin with this? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

I have a textbox which should act as a autocomplete onClientTextChanged event.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve your data from the server using [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

after that you can put your data in a variable for example called `data`

after that you use the autocomplete plugin this way:

```
 $("#example").autocomplete(data);
```

[here is another example on how to get call your webmethod using ajax](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: Just to note: $("#example").autocomplete({source: data});  you must set the source property with the array of auto complete data you wish to use

Comment: How to retrieve data from server using AJAX!?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
    success: function(data){
    $("input").autocomplete({source:data});
    }
});

<input />
```

use a json call to get and then set with autocomplete, do note you also need the jquery UI include

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Yyn7v/ - here is a jfiddle with a quick example of autocomplete with jquery UI

Comment: what should be the url? it is a page web method not web service method?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery UI you don't need no Ajax. You can just give it a Javascript array. Use this documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/